# Woocommerce - add tracking code to another email template

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I'm using the "WooCommerce UPS Shipping Plugin with Print Label" plugin to process my orders. The plugin provides the tracking code to the customer **as long as I set the order status to "completed"** (the tracking code is inserted directly into the order completed email and sent to the customer).

I'd like to provide the tracking code based on another order status, like "shipped", making the "completed" as the last step, but there's no way to do that through the plugin settings.

By contacting the support, I got this:

[image]

Can someone please help me to write this code?

Comment: Is it this plugin? [WooCommerce UPS Shipping Plugin with Print Label](https://www.pluginhive.com/product/woocommerce-ups-shipping-plugin-with-print-label/) That's a pay-for plugin so we aren't able to just get the source to look at to help you.

Comment: I'd start by searching the plugin code for "completed" to see if there are any obvious checks or status transition hook names using it. I'm afraid I don't know WooCommerce though to know if there any other or better ways of hooking on the status change.

Comment: You should also ask the plugin authors for help if you have paid support. They should be willing to point you in the right direction at least.